# adding color bar in a simple line plot with defined rainbow colors in R

Tags: r, plot

I want to make a line plot with several lines, whereby each line corresponds to a defined color. Then I want to show the color bar aside the plot. It is straightforward to define and plot the lines (as a simple example below), but I could not put the bar plot  ( I have tried different approaches). Notice: I dont want to use ggplot2.

```
n =30
color=rainbow(n, s = 1, v = 1, start = 0, end = max(1, n - 1)/n, alpha = 1)
x=seq(1:10) 
plot(x,1*x,col=color[1],type="l")
for (i in seq(2,30)){
  lines(x,i*x,col=color[i])}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a perfect example of why `ggplot` is so popular... AFAIK, drawing a colorbar legend in base R graphics requires creating a layout with two columns, and putting an `image(...)` in the second slot, as in:

```
n =30
color=rainbow(n, s = 1, v = 1, start = 0, end = max(1, n - 1)/n, alpha = 1)
layout(t(1:2),widths=c(6,1))
x=0:10
par(mar=c(4,4,1,0.5))
plot(x,1*x,col=color[1],type="l")
for (i in seq(2,30)){
  lines(x,i*x,col=color[i])}
par(mar=c(5,1,5,2.5))
image(y=2:30,z=t(2:30), col=color[2:30], axes=FALSE, main="Slope", cex.main=.8)
axis(4,cex.axis=0.8,mgp=c(0,.5,0))
```

[image]

For information on all those obscure plot parameters (`mar`, `mgp`, `cex.main`, etc., .etc), type `?par`. Also, there are also several packages that try to make this easier: [here](http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/aqfig/html/vertical.image.legend.html), and [here](http://www.image.ucar.edu/GSP/Software/Fields/Help/image.plot.html)

And, even though you didn't ask for it, a `ggplot` solution.

```
library(ggplot2)
n <- 30
df   <- expand.grid(x=0:10,slope=2:n)
df$y <- with(df,x*slope)
ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(x,y,group=slope,color=slope))+
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,10))+
  scale_color_gradientn(colours=rainbow(n))+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]